# How to fix tabbing in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tabs, ide

I have VS 2010 SP1 installed and I'm working with C#.

Tabbing doesn't work properly when I expect it to write the class name.

When I write for example "throw new NotImpl" and then press tab I expected it to write the whole word as "NotImpelementedException" but it just jumps to the next line without writing the class name!

Also when I press Ctrl+space, that lists classes, and select the class name it doesn't write the class and similarly jumps to the next line.

I have Resharper installed, could that affect it?

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ReSharper is causing the issue. It's intellisense menu is painful. Use the ENTER key and you should be fine.

One other thing you could consider is just turning off ReSharper's menus. You can do that under the options page.

[image]